# How can I declare a startup-hook in a Java Web App

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I want to do some initializing (timers and logging) when the web app is started. I cannot use a ContextListener since I dont get any of my Spring-Components within it. I need a simple hook like "afterWebAppHasLoadedAndEverythingyIsSetUp()".
Does it exist?

Answer (score 2):

The ApplicationContext publishes certain types of events when loading the beans.

Event handling in the ApplicationContext is provided through the ApplicationEvent class and ApplicationListener interface. So if a bean implements the ApplicationListener, then every time an ApplicationEvent gets published to the ApplicationContext, that bean is notified.

Following events are provided by spring

- ContextRefreshedEvent
- ContextStartedEvent
- ContextStoppedEvent
- ContextClosedEvent

Firstly create a implementation of ApplicationListener as follows

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextStartedEvent;

public class CStartEventHandler 
   implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent>{

   public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event) {
      System.out.println("ContextStartedEvent Received");
   }
}
```

Then you just have to Register the class as a bean with the Spring.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Boot (which i recommend), you can use the following CommandLineRunner bean to run your initialization stuff after the application started up. You will be able to get all the spring beans ready, below is the code snippet.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    // here you can take any number of object which is anutowired automatically
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner init(MyService service, MyRepository repository) {

        // do your stuff with the beans 

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```